# Get Keys with Multi Patterns in Redis

Tags: java, redis

I want to get all keys start with 460  or 45412.

`keys 460*  combine keys 45412*`

I try the method in this Link: https://redis.io/commands/keys but Failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally Use Jedis to get all result by Set DataStructure

```
 Set<String> FirstSet = js.keys("460*");
 Set<String> SecondSet = js.keys("45412*");
 SecondSet.addAll(FirstSet );
```

The Second Set is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `combine` option in Redis.

And `keys` command is not supposed to be used on application level, it is slow. Instead you can use appropriate type (`hash` or `zset` or its combination, depending on what you need)

Anyway, if you want to get keys by two patterns you can just call `keys` a couple times and combine results:

```
cat <(redis-cli -n 0 keys "460*") <(redis-cli -n 0 keys "45412*") > keys.txt
```